# Ext.log function is empty function

Tags: javascript, extjs

I try to use [Ext.log](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext-method-log), but `Ext.log` returns an empty function (`function () {}`)

I use `./ext-4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js`. I thought only the production build removed logging functionality.

What do I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ext-all-dev.js` instead of `ext-all-debug.js` and use `Ext.log` like this:

```
Ext.log({level:'debug'}, 'debug message');
```

Comment: jup I needed dev -> debug doesn't give you your debug messages o_O Bad naming of the package I guess...